# Is it possible to build a hive for bumblebee or hornet

Tags: zoology, entomology

People commonly build hives for honey bees and it works . Is it also possible to build a hive for a bumblebees or hornets ? Should it have any special shape or form or is it just impossible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very common practice and there are many [instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-Nest-Box-for-Bumblebees/) and [plans](http://www.bumblebee.org/nestboxes.htm) for beehives/nests available online, there are some for [wasps](https://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/ent/notes/Other/note121/note121.html)